# regex floating numbers or integers only

Tags: regex

I am trying to clean up a field so that it only has integers or floating numbers.
Basically, I want to the row to be blank if there are dates or text.

This catches most things:

regex_replace("^(\d*.\d*).*","$1")

but leaves the initial numbers if the row is a date (i.e. 2022 if 2022-07-01 20:30:29 or 7 if 7/1/2022).

0
0
1
15
1.8910127482598
2022-07-01 20:30:29
7/1/2022
West
Living
C000000475
1
0
0
0

How can I modify the regex so that it removes the dates as well?

TIA,

LCH

Comment: Cast the values to a string type.

Comment: [Here's a great site](https://regex101.com/) to experiment with regular expressions.

Comment: this `^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$` will match only valid (positive) integer and non integer numbers. It's not a replace but a match (true/false). If you need to go beyond and transform the data, you can cast to string type as suggested and trust the result

Answer (score 1):

### Find all numbers

```
^(\d*\.?\d*)$
```

Your regular expression uses `\d.\d` which is probably not intended by you. The `.` must be escaped, otherwise it will be interpreted as *"any character"*.

- Notice I wrote `\.?` to find an optional decimal point. A `.` means *"any character"*, not the decimal dot. We therefore escape it.
- I added the `$` at the end to denote *"end of line"*.
- Replacing with $1 just leaves the number. Use an empty string to remove numbers.

Find a playground on regex101 here:
https://regex101.com/r/P7jwNV/1

This is a slightly tweaked version of your expression. However, it will go through the lines and replace the number with themselves. How would that leave the other rows empty?

### Remove the numbers

You say you want to remove the non-numbers, however your regular expression is trying to find numbers and replace them with the full search result. Which is the same as not doing anything.

```
^([^:\-\/\D]+|\d+\.\d+)$
```

With your examples this will leave the non-numbers if we replace with `$1`.

See regex101 playground here:
https://regex101.com/r/VV68Pj/1

### Remove the non-numbers

Regular expressions are not for finding a pattern you then want the opposite of the matches to work on. Se we have to find the patterns we don't want to replace them with an empty string. We can classify the non-numbers separately with `|`:

```
^((?![\d]+).+|\d+\/\d+\/\d+|\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)$
```

- `?!` is a negative lookahead, in our case it finds a non-digit
- `(?![\d]+).+`: If the following does not have a digit in it...
- `\d+\/\d+\/\d+`: Or the following is a date (I escaped `/` there, you may not need to)...
- `\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+`: Or the following is a date + timestamp

We then simply replace with nothing (an empty string) to remove them.

Regex101 playground to tinker with it:
https://regex101.com/r/ZK5PDZ/1